# Runtime.getRuntime().exec is not working after selecting second textfield

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am working on this login page that has 2 textfield and a button. Whenever I click on the first textfield, the On-Screen Keyboard (osk.exe) will pop up, but when I click on the second textfield, the On-Screen keyboard doesn't seem to focus on the second textfield, meaning that I cannot type anything on the second textfield, so what I tried to do was stop osk.exe process and start it up again when I select the second textfield, but osk doesn't seem to pop out on the first click, I have to click the second time to pop it out, so it means each time I click on the textfield, it will pop out and close OSK turn by turn, can anyone help me please? two of my textfield has the following onClick method in JavaFx Scene Builder:

```
public void osk (){

    try
    {
        killProcess();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\Temp\\osk.exe");

    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

                    }



 public static void killProcess() throws Exception {

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.exec("taskkill " + "osk.exe");

    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "taskkill /IM " + "osk.exe" );

 }
```

edit: I added more description, sorry for not including it earlier.

Comment: So `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` is working just fine, and the problem is actually either in your focus handling, or in your usage of OSK, correct? You may wish to rephrase your question to more accurately describe the problem, and post code that is more relevant as well, as `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` seems to be working as advertised.

Comment: I've debugged and you code is working fine for both running OSK and killng process. Are you sure you don't want to run OSK from system32 dir?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading title, I've changed it already, hope it clear things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it myself, it turns out that I have to delay the thread for a second, else the OSK would not have the opportunity to pop up, and thus killed. Correct me if I am wrong

```
 try
    {

     killProcess();


     try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
         }    catch(InterruptedException ex) 

         {
              Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
         }



     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\Temp\\osk.exe");

    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`taskkill` is a windows cmd command. I think you could try replace `rt.exec("taskkill " + "osk.exe");` by `rt.exec("cmd.exe /c taskkill " + "osk.exe");`

Comment: The code does close down the OSK process, but OSK doesnt seem to pop up automatically when I select the second textfield, instead I have to click on the 2nd textfield again to pop up OSK

Comment: @Artest113 ok, so I misunderstood your question. You could try to get the inputstream of the process and read all the output, then use `exec()` to execute a new command